# What's the best way to publish dynamic parameters to a topic when they change?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, parameters, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to publish dynamic parameters (from dynamic_reconfigure) to a topic from a C++ node when they change, for the purpose of recording parameter changes in a bag file. In Python, I just convert the dynamic parameters object to a string and publish it in the dynamic parameters callback. What's the best way to do something similar in C++, without having to manually copy each field of the param struct into a string?

Python:

```
def update_dynamic_params(self, dynamic_params, _level):
    # this always works and I don't have to change the code when the cfg file changes
    self.param_pub.publish(str(dynamic_params))
```

C++:

```
void MyNode::updateDynamicParams(const MyConfig& dynamic_params, uint32_t level)
{
  // I'd like to avoid manually copying each field of MyConfig struct into a string, especially because I'd have to update it each time the cfg file changes
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280994/what%27s-the-best-way-to-publish-dynamic-parameters-to-a-topic-when-they-change?/) by [somudrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2500/somudrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-29**:
Do you want to publish **only** if the parameter changes?

**Comment by [somudrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2500/somudrog/) on 2018-01-29**:
Yes. Please see my updated question details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two topics `/node_name/parameter_descriptions` and `/node_name/parameter_updates` that are published when you run a dynamic reconfigure server. The latter publishes the parameters whenever you update them - which is what you need.

---

Originally posted by [prem](https://answers.ros.org/users/33465/prem/) with karma: 46 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3